# Access Html string returned by controller method programmatically when testing C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am trying to test one of the views. First I authenticate and Login user to get needed Cookies information, then I want to check the look of IndexView from HomeController.

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void IndexView()
    {
        // Setup Moq config for controller context
        moqContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        moqRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        moqResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        moqSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        moqServer = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

        var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity("User");
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, null);

        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(moqResponse.Object);
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Response.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(moqSession.Object);
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Server).Returns(moqServer.Object);
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(principal);

        var contextRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost:port/User/Login", "");
        var contextResponse = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(contextRequest, contextResponse);
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        // Authenticate User
        IUserAppService _usuarioApp = _container.GetInstance<IUserAppService>();
        var user = _usuarioApp.AutenticateUser("user", "password");

        var userController = _container.GetInstance<UserController>();
        userController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(moqContext.Object, new RouteData(), userController);
        var res = userController.RealizaLogin(true, "", user) as RedirectToRouteResult;

        foreach (var key in moqContext.Object.Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            var cookieItem = moqContext.Object.Response.Cookies[key];
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookieItem);
            moqContext.Object.Request.Cookies.Add(cookieItem);
        }

        var homeController = _container.GetInstance<HomeController>();
        homeController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(moqContext.Object, new RouteData(), userController);
        var result = homeController.Index() as ViewResultBase;
        //here do not know what to do
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to get this rendered HTML. Is there any way?

Comment: There are ways to UI test your application? Is that what you mean? For example you can use selenium. There are many. Is this what you want?

Comment: I assume you have to call [`ExecuteResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.viewresultbase.executeresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ViewResultBase_ExecuteResult_System_Web_Mvc_ControllerContext_) handing it that controllerContext instance.

Comment: @panoskarajohn, The point is to 'see' the view how the user see it and check critical elements on view if they match.

Comment: @rene You might be right, I tried to use ExecuteResult but I receive nullReferenceException on `System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.GetDisplayMode()`

Comment: Yeah, you're moving yourself into an swamp that you can only escape from if you mock the whole asp.net http handling pipeline. Can't you just spin up the dev server as part of your test start-up and have that serve the page for you?

Comment: @rene, I dont understand, you mean to not write at all the test for a view?

Comment: No, I mean you have to take a different approach. Just serve that view by using the ASP.NET infrastructure, invoke it with an httpclient and inspect its results.